# Select column from GroupBy for boxplot

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset I'd like to group by a certain field and then draw one or more boxplots of a single column. I am trying to do the grouping once then select each column in turn, but boxplot seems to draw all columns regardless.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

animals = pd.DataFrame({'kind': ['cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog', 'cat', 'dog'],
                        'height': [9.1, 6.0, 9.5, 34.0, 8.0, 30.0],
                        'weight': [7.9, 7.5, 9.9, 198.0, 8.0, 150.0]})
```

Grouping by 'kind' and then boxplot gives me four boxes (cat, height) (cat, weight) (dog,height) (dog,weight) as expected.

```
grouped = animals.groupby('kind')
grouped.boxplot(subplots=False)
```

Now if I just want the height I thought this would work:

```
grouped[["height"]].boxplot(subplots=False)
```

but I just get the same four boxes.

I know I can do

```
animals.boxplot(column="height", by="kind")
```

and this gives me what I want, but this seems inefficient; if I have 10 columns I am doing the grouping ten times.

To clarify, I want something like

```
grouped = mydata.groupby('something')
for col_name in [...column_names...]:
  grouped[[col_name]].boxplot(...)
  ...save plot to file
```

i.e. one grouping operation and many boxplots.

What is the correct way to select columns out of a `DataFrameGroupBy`?

Using pandas 0.25.1 and Python 3.7.3

Answer (score 0):

may be you need something like this ?

```
grouped_df = animals.groupby('kind')[['height']].apply(lambda x: x.reset_index(drop=True)).reset_index(level=0)

grouped_df.groupby('kind').boxplot(subplots=False)
plt.show()
```

Comment: I don't think so; not sure what the `apply` part does but isn't that grouping twice by kind? I clarified the question which will help, I hope

Comment: @PeterHull first groupby takes as much columns as you want (in case of many columns that you want to separate while plotting boxplot) and makes it dataframe with the help of apply function.  Now, you will only have those columns which are required for the boxplot and then you can simply use plotting function. I thought this is what you wanted.